# Глючит исключение пользователя из вопросов по метке

Tags: дефект, поддержка, поиск

[`[соревнование] is:q цикл`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%5D+is%3Aq+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB) - 2 результата / 2 results
[`-user:178988 [соревнование] is:q цикл`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-user%3A178988+%5B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%5D+is%3Aq+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB) - работает - 1 результат / OK - 1 result
[`-user:10105 [соревнование] is:q цикл`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-user%3A10105+%5B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%5D+is%3Aq+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB) - не работает - 2 результата / NOT OK - 2 results

Я ожидаю, что будут найдены вопросы по метке, которые заданы пользователем, отличным от указанного. Но реально работает как-то по другому. Как оно работает и как мне составить интересующий меня запрос?

I expect it to find questions with specified tag asked by anyone except specific user. But it works in some other way. How does it work and how can I make the query I want to use?